# Ordering output of C++ std::set

Tags: c++, set, stdset

I want to list the output of my set in alphabetical order. Below is an attempt at getting to this, but it seems slow / inefficient and I haven't even finished it yet.

```
void ordered(ostream &os) {
    bool inserted = false;
    for (objects::iterator i = begin(); i != end(); ) {
        for (objects::iterator x = begin(); x != end(); ++x) {
            if((**i) < (**x)) { //overloaded and works
                os << **i << endl;
                inserted = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(inserted) {
            ++i;
        }
    }
}
```

Clearly this will only output objects that come after the first object alphabetically.

I also considered moving the objects from a set into another container but it still seems inefficient.

Comment: @AlexanderMyshov It's great that you're trying to improve posts here, but please try to find something more substantial to improve than a single tag edit. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The `std::set` is an ordered container, see reference:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set

> `std::set` is an associative container that contains a **sorted set** of
>   unique objects of type `Key`. Sorting is done using the key comparison
>   function Compare. Search, removal, and insertion operations have
>   logarithmic complexity. Sets are usually implemented as red-black
>   trees.

Answer (score 0):

`std::set` is already ordered. It looks like you merely need to use a custom comparer that compares the pointed-to values instead of the pointers themselves (which is the default):

```
template<typename T> struct pless {
    inline bool operator()(const T* a, const T* b) const { return *a < *b; }
};
std::set<Foo*, pless<Foo> > objects;
```